# How to apply the bcrypt also how to fetch data

Tags: php

When I try to login it doesn't display any information, it didn't get the data in database.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    //filter this variable for security
    $username = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['username'])));
    $password = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['password'])));

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM students WHERE s_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $user = $stmt->fetch();
    if($user == FALSE) {
        die("Incorrect");
    }else {

        $password_hash = $user['password'];

        $validPassword = password_verify($password, $password_hash);

         if($validPassword){

            echo "success";

        } else{
            //$validPassword was FALSE. Passwords do not match.
            echo 'Incorrect username / password combination!<br/>';
            echo $user['password'];
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Do you get any results? Is `$user['id']` set? Shouldn't `s_id` be integer?

Comment: mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given

Answer (score 0):

Your query only selects the id.  Change your query to select your id and password.

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM students WHERE s_id = ?");
```

Then you will have your hashed password  `$user['password']` in the results.

Comment: still doesn't display the $user['password']

Comment: How to fetch the data? cause my fetch is blank

Comment: the point is that the db field `password` is not in the recordset

Comment: `SELECT password FROM students WHERE s_id = ?`

Comment: $user = $stmt->fetch(); I already tried $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::OBJ);

Comment: it just the same sir @RamRaider.
either * or password, still doesn't display

Comment: please `print_r($user)` after your do your query.  Please post the results in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to wrap everything in a `try/catch` block and raise exceptions at key points to determine where the code breaks. Also I think the result from the query should be bound to a variable prior to fetching the results using `$stmt->bind_result`

When using a prepared statement I'd suggest that you do NOT use `mysqli_real_escape_string` nor use `trim` as it would be perfectly valid for a password to start or end with a space - the database engine will process the statement in a manner that is safe.

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']) ){
    try{

        $args=array(
            'username'  =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'password'  =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
        );
        $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
        extract( $_POST );


        $stmt = $conn->prepare("select `password` from `students` where `s_id` = ?");
        if( $stmt ){

            $stmt->bind_param( "s", $username );
            $result = $stmt->execute();

            if( $result ){

                /* There should be only 1 record - bind to a variable */
                $stmt->bind_result( $pwdhash );

                /* fetch the results of the query */
                $stmt->fetch();

                /* is the password correct? */
                $validpassword = password_verify( $password, $pwdhash );

                echo $validpassword ? 'Success' : 'Error: Incorrect username or password';


                $stmt->close();


            } else {
                throw new Exception('No results returned');
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception('failed to prepare sql query');
        }
    } catch( Exception $e ){
        exit( $e->getMessage() );
    }
}
```

Comment: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

Comment: Really? The sql selects one column and binds one variable